# Understanding the use_dis_max parameter in Elasticsearch and its replacement in versions 7 and 8

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working with Elasticsearch and came across the **use_dis_max** parameter, but I am unsure about its purpose and usage. Can someone please explain what **use_dis_max** does and provide an example to demonstrate its functionality? Additionally, I would like to know if there have been any changes in Elasticsearch versions 7 and 8 regarding this parameter and if it has been replaced with something else.